# Like button in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to make a like button to like a recipe and adds all users id who like recipe into array **voters** and later want to stop the user liking same recipe multiple times by using ._contains, however same user still able to like it multiple time.Can you please help me where i am making mistake?

complete source code [Github](https://github.com/soni1/foody)

```
Template.recipes.events({
    "click [data-action='addLikes']": function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (_.contains(Recipes.voters, Meteor.userId()))
            FlashMessages.sendError("You already liked this recipe", {hideDelay: 1000});
        Recipes.update(this._id, {$addToSet: {voters: Meteor.userId()}, $inc: {likes: 1}});
    }
});
```

**collections.html**

```
Recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes');
Recipes.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    ownerId: {
        type: String
    },
    ownerName: {
        type: String

    },
    voters:{
      type:Array,
      optional:true
    },
    'voters.$':{
      type:String
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Recipe Name",
        max: 100
    },

        ingredients: {
            type: [Object],
            minCount: 1
        },

    "ingredients.$.name": {
    type: String
        },
    "ingredients.$.amount": {
    type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        label: "How to prepare ",
    },
    time: {
        type: Number,
        label: "Time (Minutes)",
        min:0
    },
    likes:{
        type:Number,
        optional:true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "cfs-file",
                collection: 'recipesImages',
                label: 'Recipe Picture'
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

**add_recipes.html**

```
<template name="add_recipes">
    <div class="container">
        {{#autoForm collection="Recipes" id="insertRecipes" type="insert"}}
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Add a Recipe</legend>
                {{> afQuickField name='name'}}
                {{> afQuickField name='ingredients'}}
                {{> afQuickField name='description' rows=6}}
                {{> afQuickField name='time'}}
                {{> afQuickField name="image" }}
                {{> afQuickField name="likes" value="0" type="hidden" }}
                {{> afQuickField name='ownerId' type="hidden" value=currentUserId}}
                {{> afQuickField name='ownerName' type="hidden" value=currentUserName}}
                {{> afQuickField name='voters' type="hidden" value=""}}
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Recipe</button>
        {{/autoForm}}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to find an actual recipe in your if block.  Something like:

```
event.preventDefault();
var recipe = Recipes.findOne({ _id: this._id });
if( recipe ) {
  if (_.contains(recipe.voters, Meteor.userId())) {
      FlashMessages.sendError("You already liked this recipe", {hideDelay: 1000});
  }
  Recipes.update(this._id, {$addToSet: {voters: Meteor.userId()}, $inc: {likes: 1}});
}
```

Comment: After sending error message we have to return false ,otherwise it still adds the like. @Stephen Woods